# How do I troubleshoot why I have upload problems with speedtest.net?

Tags: networking, cable

I have cable and I have historically been able to run speedtest.net without issues. Google seems to work fine, but other sites like my bank and facebook have intermittent connections. I run tracert and no really high pings. What other things can I do to troubleshoot my connection. The problem occurs on all 3 computers that I have (Win7 RTM, WinXP SP3, OSX 10.5)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? A lot more detail would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So your download is fine but your upload is limited?

Do you know what your service provider has your service rated for?

What type of connections are you using? Wired?  Wireless?

Describe the intermittent connection.

Have you tried configuring your router with the OpenDNS servers instead of the default?

Comment: Changing DNS servers isn't going to affect upload speed.

Comment: True, this is to troubleshoot the intermittent connection issue.